# Freebase MQL Query to fetch all instances and their Wiki description

Tags: freebase, mql

I want to fetch and save Wikipedia descriptions of all instances from /sports/sport to my database.

It requires 2 API calls  - one to fetch mid and another to fetch wiki description. Is it possible to combine the 2 queries to a single query?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The API isn't really designed for bulk downloads.  There's a dump file available for these types of bulk operations.  https://developers.google.com/freebase/data#freebase-rdf-dumps

If you were searching for a specific sport or sports, you could get both the description and MID using the Search API e.g. [https://www.googleapis.com/freebase/v1/search?indent=true&filter=(all%20type:/sports/sport)&output=(description)](https://www.googleapis.com/freebase/v1/search?indent=true&filter=%28all%20type:/sports/sport%29&output=%28description%29)

Don't forget that you need to cite Wikipedia as well as Freebase, since you're using their text.

Comment: Actually I was looking to know whether it is possible through MQL API. However, your solution made me to think about the other alternative. Thanks a lot for your time.

Comment: The MQLread API doesn't have access to the text descriptions, unfortunately.